# Windows Phone 8 Bluetooth Address

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8

Im currently working on developing an app for Windows Phone 8 and one requierment is to display the phones local Bluetooth address/device id.

Is this possible? 
If so does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this first off all enable the capapbility device identity and then write this

```
 byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
string DeviceIDAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);
```

this might help you......

Comment: I tried that and it works fine to get the UniqueDeviceID, but not the BluetoothAddress which is most important.

Comment: what is the use of the bluetooth address ...  do you want list of paired devices ?

Comment: The address needs to be sent to our server appliction for verification and to be used in our own hardware. And this is done without pairing, so the list of paired devices isnt an issue (yet)

Answer (score 0):

after finding all peers, you open socket to a peer then you have:

```
peerSocket.Information.LocalAddress
```